# PHP Function Redirect Header fails

Tags: php, redirect

Anyone know why this script does not work?

When I redirect it redirects me to `website.com//google.com/` its not adding the https or http

```
public function redirect($url, $permanent = false) {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') {
        $protocol = 'https';
    } else {
        $protocol = 'http';
    }
    $domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

    header('Location: ' . $protocol . '://' . $domain . '/' . $url,true,$permanent ? 301 : 302);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Check your log for "Headers already sent" warnings and fix the problem.

Comment: What is the value of `$url` when you call `redirect()`? The function always puts your own domain in the redirect, so you can only redirect to a different page in the site, not to a different site like google.com.

Comment: Use the Network tab of Dev Tools to see the exact contents of the `Location:` header. What is it?

Comment: check this `var_dump('Location: ' . $protocol . '://' . $domain . '/' . $url);` I hope so you find out the problem.

Comment: You should just use `if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']))`. The documentation doesn't say that the value is `on/off`.

Comment: When using `$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, you add your own domain as part of the final destination

Comment: Comment out the `header` function and log what you are working with. What happened to the previous question on this? You shouldn't delete questions and post the same one as a new question.

Comment: it shows string(14) "Location: :///" the var dump

Comment: Fixed is there a way to make it so if my domain is set it would use the domain ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) for the redirect? or would I need to set two functions one for no domain and one for a domain?

Comment: Unclear why you have `$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];` or would have that. `$url` seems like the domain you want to be directing to. Please add more details to the question so we can assist.